# google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Bad Request', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Bad Request'})

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I have generated developer_token, access_token and refresh token with googleads read permission. While using in code using google-ads-api I am getting below error.

Code:

```
from google.ads.googleads.client import GoogleAdsClient
googleads_client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage(path="./googleads.yaml", version="v14")
```

Error:

```
  googleads_client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage(path="./googleads.yaml", version="v14")
```

I followed [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-adwords-kpis-reports-via-api-python-step-by-step-guide-245fc74d9d73) tutorial to generate developer token, access token and refresh_token.

Here is permissions in the app and during authorization screenshot
[image]

[image]

Comment: try getting a new refresh token

Comment: Already tried that as well